# Pdf missing signature after uploading from ASP.NET MVC XMLHttpRequest

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, digital-signature

I'm working on a ASP.NET MVC page to let users upload a Pdf document once they have digitally signed it.
But for some reason the signature is destroyed when uploading the document even when it's graphic representation is properly displayed.
Here is the code I use to upload the file:

```
    $(document).on('click', 'input[value=Upload]', function (e, argument) {
        var formdata = new FormData();
        for (i = 0; i < document.getElementById('FileBox').files.length; i++) {
            formdata.append(document.getElementById('FileBox').files[i].name, document.getElementById('FileBox').files[i]);
        }

        var url = '@Url.Action("Upload", "Test")'

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', url);
        xhr.send(formdata);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                var response = $.parseJSON(xhr.response);
                alert(response.result);
            }
        }
    });
```

I'm retrieving the uploaded files in the controller as follows:

```
Public Function PostedFiles() As List(Of Byte())
    Dim retval As New List(Of Byte())
    Dim oRequest As HttpRequest = Web.HttpContext.Current.Request
    For Each sFileKey As String In oRequest.Files
        Dim oFile As HttpPostedFile = oRequest.Files(sFileKey)
        If oFile.ContentLength > 0 Then
            Dim iLength As Integer = oFile.ContentLength
            Dim oBytes(iLength) As Byte
            Dim oStream As System.IO.Stream = oFile.InputStream()
            oStream.Read(oBytes, 0, iLength)
            retval.Add(oBytes)
        End If
    Next
    Return retval
End Function
```

After persisting the byte arrays in a SQL server database, when I take them back from the database there is no longer any signature, just the graphic representation of it.

Comment: You observed the issue *after persisting the byte arrays in a SQL server database*; have you checked whether the files returned by `PostedFiles()` *before persisting to the database* already have that issue? If they don't, you look for the culprit in the wrong code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Mkl for your comment, I realize I was getting no signature since the document was displayed in the browser. Opening the persisted file in Acrobat Reader successfully shows the signature.